# Как при наведении на элемент изменить его цвет и цвет соседнего элемената

Tags: html, css

Имеется прозрачная и закрашенная картинка звезды, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на вторую звезду, менялась и вторая и первая звезда на закрашеную звезду?

Answer (score 4):

```css
main {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

div {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div + div {
  margin-right: .25em;
}

div:hover, div:hover ~ div {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>1</div>
</main>
```

И более комфортный вариант:

```css
main {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

div {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

section + section {
  padding-right: .25em;
}

section:hover div, section:hover ~ section div {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section><div>5</div></section>
  <section><div>4</div></section>
  <section><div>3</div></section>
  <section><div>2</div></section>
  <section><div>1</div></section>
</main>
```

И для круглой формы:

```css
main {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

div {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

section {
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
  position: relative;
}

section + section {
  padding-right: 1.25em;
  margin-right: -1em;
}

section:hover div, section:hover ~ section div {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section style="z-index:5"><div>5</div></section>
  <section style="z-index:4"><div>4</div></section>
  <section style="z-index:3"><div>3</div></section>
  <section style="z-index:2"><div>2</div></section>
  <section style="z-index:1"><div>1</div></section>
</main>
```

PS: Можно сделать аналогично с помощью `float: right`.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Просто и полезно

Answer (score 2):

```css
section, div {
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

section:hover > div {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<section><div>1</div>
  <section><div>2</div>
    <section><div>3</div>
      <section><div>4</div>
        <section><div>5</div>
</section></section></section></section></section>
```

При желании можно применить тот же фокус для кругов:

```css
section, div {
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

section:hover > div {
  background: antiquewhite;
}

section section {
  border-radius: 2em 0 0 2em;
}
```

```html
<section><div>1</div>
  <section><div>2</div>
    <section><div>3</div>
      <section><div>4</div>
        <section><div>5</div>
</section></section></section></section></section>
```

Comment: если ещё кликабельно сделаешь ...то есть что бы сохранялось состояние ..будет ваще атас

Comment: @MaximLensky, это не просили. Но надо просто заменить div на label и кинуть радиобаттоны в самое начало.

Comment: я знаю как это сделать...но хочу посмотреть как это делают другие `Коллеги по Цеху` ...